# LXC container templates?

Tags: lxc

Is it possible to create an LXC container that you maintain only for the purpose of copying as a template?  If so, how does one properly copy an LXC container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, an LXC container is some config files and a directory within the whole server. If you copy this directory and config files and adjust the parameters you can use it as a template. Just tar it and untar it to the new machine's directory.

Comment: Where do I configure the cgroup?   The copy is trying to use the same one as my "original"

Comment: nevermind...i shouldn't copy live machines :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily obtained using BTRFS filesystem in combination with snapshots.

The template filesystem must reside in a subvolume on a btrfs filesystem, say

```
btrfs subvolume create /mnt/btrfs/template
```

After which you can populate it.

To create the snapshot:

```
btrfs subvolume snapshot /mnt/btrfs/template /mnt/btrfs/node-1
```

Afterwards remove the snapshot with:

```
btrfs subvolume delete delete /mnt/btrfs/node-1
```

Advantages are that:

- creation and removal is fast
- no extra space is needed, only changed files (blocks) occupy extra space

Further on, if you want to provide your container with some writable private directories on top of a read-only template filesystem you could use *mount -o bind* from **within** the container

```
 mount -o bind /mnt/btrfs/node-1/var /var
```

Answer (score 1):

I also use a main template for all my containers.

If you are using Ubuntu 14.04, [lxc-clone](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html#lxc-cloning) is your friend to create new container based off a template.

```
lxc-clone -o template_container -n new_container
```